# Powershell - Check IP, loop to retry and send email

Tags: powershell

I've been trying to script so powershell checks our external ip - if its unchanged - do nothing just log its been checked.

If the script thinks its changed, retry, and if after 5 attempts it has changed then send an email.

I've included where I got to, but I can't (tiredness or stupidity) get this to work today so throwing this out to the hive mind for help!

attached is where ive got too!  Cheers CM

```
 #find old ip
$oldip = gc .\ip.txt

#get current ip address
$currentip = (New-Object net.webclient).downloadstring("http://api.ipify.org")

#current date and time
$currentTime = Get-Date -format "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"

#script location
$scriptpath = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition 
[string]$dir = Split-Path $scriptpath  
set-location $dir

#set the smtp server URL here
$smtpServer = "smtp.my.com"

#Set the Sender Name or Email here
$sender = "sender@my.comm"

#Enter the email reciepients here - you can send to multiple using format: "user1@gmail.com", "user2@hotmail.com";
$users = "email@my.com";

#Enter the subject title the reciepient see's here
$subject = "IP Has Changed" 

#Type out the email contents here
$body = "Dear Team Member,

Your IP address at has just changed from:  $oldip

And is now set too:  $currentip 

Regards." 


#*****************************************************************************************************************************************

do {
    $Result = ($oldip -ne $currentip)
    if ($Result.Status -eq "Success") {
        Write-Output "IP Address Unchanged - Monitoring Continues."
        Add-Content $PSScriptRoot\IP_Check_Log.txt "$currentTime - IP Unchanged. "
        Start-Sleep -s 2
        Exit 0
    }
    else {
       Write-Output "Ping Failed!"
       Add-Content $PSScriptRoot\IP_Check_Log.txt "$currentTime - IP Check Failed - Retrying"
       $Failures += 5
    }
} until ($Failures -ge $FailureThreshold)
Write-Output "IP Address Changed!"
Add-Content $PSScriptRoot\IP_Check_Log.txt "$currentTime - IP Adderss Changed. "
Add-Content $PSScriptRoot\IP_Check_Log.txt "*****************************************************************************"

#be sure to alter the SMTP server port here if needed.
    $smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer, 587) 
    $smtp.EnableSsl = $true 

#Enter the sending email address and password here
    $smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("email@my.com", "password"); 
    $smtp.Send($sender, $user, $subject, $body)
```

Comment: What isn't working and how does it fail?

Comment: your `$Result` variable should be a boolean ... but you are testing for `$Result.Status`. that property otta not be there.

Comment: Hi Mathias, It always returns as failed - im assuming i've missed something obvious but it's been a rough day - hoping fresh eyes would spot the mistake!!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps easier than a `do{..} until(..)` here is to loop using a `for` loop and I would use a `try{..} catch{..}` on this.

Inside the loop get the ip address fresh, don't get that once and keep looping over that instance.

Something like this perhaps (left out the emailing stuff)

```
$logFile = Join-Path -Path $PSScriptRoot -ChildPath 'IP_Check_Log.txt'
$FailureThreshold = 5

# find old ip
$oldip = [IPAddress](Get-Content .\ip.txt)

$ipchanged = $false
$currentip = $null
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $FailureThreshold; $i++) {
    try {
        # try to get the get current ip address
        $currentip = [IPAddress](New-Object net.webclient).DownloadString("http://api.ipify.org")
        if ($currentip -eq $oldip) {
            Write-Output "IP Address Unchanged - Monitoring Continues."
            Add-Content -Path $logFile -Value "$currentTime - IP Unchanged. "
            exit 0
        }
        else {
            $ipchanged = $true
        }
    }
    catch {
        $currentip = $null
        $ipchanged = $false
        Write-Output "Ping Failed!"
        Add-Content -Path $logFile -Value "$currentTime - IP Check Failed - Retrying"
    }
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
}

# test if the above returned a $currentip not $null and if boolean $ipchanged is $true
if (($currentip) -and $ipchanged) {
    Write-Output "IP Address Changed!"
    Add-Content  -Path $logFile -Value "$currentTime - IP Address Changed. "
    Add-Content  -Path $logFile -Value "*****************************************************************************"

    # refresh the .\ip.txt file to store the new ip?
    Set-Content -Path .\ip.txt -Value $currentip.IPAddressToString

    # send the email
}
```

<sup>I use casts to `[IPAddress]` because if the `.DownloadString()` fails OR it returns something which is not an IP address, you will enter the catch block so you can deal with the error</sup>